# why column name is wrong after using pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

Based on this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKs1Vgtb1do:

```
import pandas as pd
names1880 = pd.read_csv('yob1880.txt', names={'name', 'sex', 'births'})
names1880.head(10)

Out[34]:

      births name   sex
0       Mary    F  7065
1       Anna    F  2604
2       Emma    F  2003
3  Elizabeth    F  1939
4     Minnie    F  1746
5   Margaret    F  1578
6        Ida    F  1472
7      Alice    F  1414
8     Bertha    F  1320
9      Sarah    F  1288

ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/P4DA$ head yob1880.txt 
Mary,F,7065
Anna,F,2604
Emma,F,2003
Elizabeth,F,1939
Minnie,F,1746
Margaret,F,1578
Ida,F,1472
Alice,F,1414
Bertha,F,1320
Sarah,F,1288
```

Question> Why the column name order of `names1880.head(10)` is not correct?

The code prints:

```
Out[34]:

      births name   sex
```

I expect:

```
Out[34]:

      name sex births
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this line:

```
names1880 = pd.read_csv('yob1880.txt', names={'name', 'sex', 'births'})
```

The `{'a','b','c'}` syntax makes a `set`, and sets are unordered.

```
>>> {'name', 'sex', 'births'}
set(['births', 'name', 'sex'])
```

Use a `list` or a `tuple` instead:

```
>>> ['name', 'sex', 'births']
['name', 'sex', 'births']
>>> ('name', 'sex', 'births')
('name', 'sex', 'births')
```